# android plain white background without gradient

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have set the background of my Android app to white and used the light theme to try and get a white background. I did so by setting the following attributes in the Manifest:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

This gives me a white background but there is also a color gradient from light gray to white. I would like to have the background a plain solid white with no gradient. Is there some way of easily achieving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a lot of different ways to do it. Just pick **one**, though.

#### Option 1

Set the background of each of your layouts to be `android:background="@android:color/white"` or `android:background="#ffff"`.

#### Option 2

If you don't want to maintain this across your app, you could use `android:background="@color/background"` then make a resource file with `<color name='background'>#ffff</color>`.

#### Option 3

Another alternative is to make a `FrameLayout` file which you always use in `setContentView()` and which has your background color (as per option 1), then inflate your other layouts within it.

#### Option 4

You can do it through Java code, using `layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));`.

#### Option 5

Extend the theme and change its background:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then, in your manifest,

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Option 5 removed the gradient. The other options changed the background color but did not remove the gradient. Thank you.

Comment: @user1696698 Oh, that's interesting. Oh, well, glad one of them worked! :)