# Android, the top of the layout looks transparent

Tags: android, image

I have a layout with a background image and also a list view that each element in it has a a background image as well.

The problem is that the top of the layout or the first few elements in the list view looks transparent (only the background image looks like that, the text looks ok) take a look at the pictures to understand more

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

Look at the second picture you can see it clearly
on the first few elements you can breally see the background image..

as well for the first picture, you can see the border of the picture only at the bottom of the screen.

Both background images are one color (no gradient or effect, normal grey color)

Any ideas?

Comment: to me it looks like that the background image is a gradient.

Comment: @metaxas4 Look at the second picture.. all items have the same background image.. How does it possible that first elements looks different then the last ones. I think this is some android default effect, that I don't know how to disable.

Comment: at the second picture i see at the buttom that the background is white, and at top as gray.

Comment: @metaxas4 so you say the background (I mean the background of the activity not the background image on each element) has a gradient? this is possible... how do i disable that?

Comment: you said that you have a layout with background image, so change this background image to color to check for differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter the same problem the problem is that by default the background is not plain white..

this solves it
[android plain white background without gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800276/android-plain-white-background-without-gradient?answertab=oldest#tab-top)